# Post-receive hook in bare

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have a bare repository. I have a non-bare repository. 
In my bare repository I have the following:

```
git --work-tree=/C:/user/gitlab/data diff-tree --name-status -r master develop
```

Here we have master and develop branch inside the non-bare repository
This works fine when I run it in the work-tree (non-bare repository)

When I put this inside my bare repository (/user/gitlab/shared.git/hooks) in post-receive it doesn't work.

I tried what is above.
I don't know how exactly to compare my master branch and my develop branch with each other and show it's status.

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do 
      git --work-tree=/C:/user/gitlab/data/ diff-tree --name-status -r master develop
done
```

Is it possible to compare two branches in your bare repository when pushing to it on you non-bare repository? (This is after committing your files)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are working with hooks in bare repositories, you need to be aware that you never actually compare two *branches*.  This is true regardless of which definition you use for the word *branch* (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).  What you really compare here, with `git diff-tree`, is two *commits*.<sup>1</sup>

Fundamentally, a *name* like `master`—which is really `refs/heads/master`—or `v2.1`, which is really `refs/tags/v2.1`, just holds a commit hash ID.  That's *a* hash ID, as in one, single, lonely hash ID.  See the linked question for how that one hash ID can represent more than one commit.

Commands like those in the `git diff` family that want to look at a *commit* will translate the name into a raw hash ID, then proceed as if you had typed in the raw hash ID.  Hence if you run:

```
git rev-parse master
```

and it prints `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017`, you could write the big ugly hash ID wherever you wrote `master`.  What's special about *branch names* is that they *move*, and do so automatically—but when you're in pre- and post-receive hooks, you must be extra-careful about this, because the *times* when they move are tricky.  That's why you are supposed to use loops like:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref; do ...; done
```

These loops read in three items: two hash IDs and a full reference name.  The two hash IDs are the *previous* value of the reference—the hash that used to be how the full reference name would resolve—and the *new* value, the hash ID that the reference will represent soon.  The last item is the full name: `refs/heads/master`, `refs/tags/v2.1`, and so on.  The front part of the name tells you what *kind* of name it is, and the rest of the name, after stripping off the front part, is the branch or tag or other name.

In a *pre-receive* or *update* hook, the name itself has not yet changed at all, so the name should resolve to the old hash.  Your hook's job is to verify whether these proposed updates should be allowed.  In a post-receive hook, the name itself *has* changed.  You are supposed to use the hash ID, not resolve the name to a hash ID now, because *another* change may be pending or have occurred as well, depending on how slow your post-receive hook itself is.

Any output you generate in a pre-receive or update hook will be copied to whoever is going the `git push` operation that triggered the hook to run.  (This output will be prefixed with the word `remote:` and it will not appear until you send a complete line.)  Any output you generate in a post-receive hook will be discarded!  If you want it saved on the server, you must send it to a log file or logging service or similar.

There's no need for your `--work-tree` argument (and it's probably unwise to use one), but you will probably need to do your work in a pre-receive or update hook, and use the raw hash IDs as appropriate.  It's up to you to figure out whether you want the updated values of both `refs/heads/master` *and* `refs/heads/develop`, if those two names are proposed to be updated, or not.  It's also up to you whether to print the result of a `git diff-tree` if *neither* `refs/heads/master` *nor* `refs/heads/develop` are proposed to be updated.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can compare trees directly, and there are forms of `git diff-tree` that produce a *combined* diff of more than two trees, but using `master develop` here you're pretty clearly selecting the tip commits of `master` and `develop`.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you!

Comment: So in the end I cannot go to my bare repository inside post-receive and compare the two commits from master and feature branch? (As it's not the best way?)

Comment: It just doesn't make sense as formulated. Your post-receive hook is invoked *because* some name(s) were updated. Read standard input (all lines) to find out which names, and what their old and new hash IDs were. You can use those to generate email or some other off-line type output and send it somewhere, but you can't send it directly to the person running `git push`.

Comment: You are right. I was confused. This makes sense now. Thanks you!